# Pretty printing in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

Is there a way to override the pretty-print that Chrome's console uses for JavaScript objects? I'm thinking about how HTML elements show up like so:

[image]

Instead of showing the standard `{}`, it shows the XML markup used to create that object. Can I achieve something similar with my own objects?

Clarification: I'm interested in printing objects in my own format, not in XML format. For example, I'd like an instance of Foo with value 3 to be logged as as `Foo(3)`

Comment: In what way would you want a regular object printed in that format? object as XML ie `<object><somepropname value="value"></object>`? If so you would probably have to do the conversion yourself then log the resulting xml

Comment: I interested in printing objects in my own format, not in XML format. For example, I'd like an instance of Foo with value 3 to be logged as as `Foo(3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DevTools APIs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/console/console-reference?hl=en) to print in whichever required available format you need.

```
console.dirxml(object);
```

I think console.log internally uses this api if the parameter passed is a DOM object.

The above method prints the object in XML format and there are many other APIs like printing in directory format `console.dir(object)` and many others. But you cannot create your own template, you must use the console.APIs provided by Dev-Tools.

Comment: Yes, add a request to Addy Osmani. Lets check if that can be provided in future. By the time, just try grouping `console.group(object[, object, …])` if it helps cool, otherwise.!